# Set a background image width & height, with aspect ratio

Tags: html, css

I search the solution on this forum and on internet, most solution available but nothing work for my case... Or I don't understand maybe.

I have a background image, and I would like this take 100% of width and same value for the height.

```css
.top-section {
  background: url('../img-content/Bg1.png') no-repeat center center fixed;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="top-section"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
html, body {   height: 100%; }

.top-section {    
  width: 100%;   
  height: 100%;   
  background-image: url("'../img-content/Bg1.png");   
  background-attachment: fixed;   background-size: cover; 
}
```

For other Image use similar

```
.top-section2 {
  width: 100%;   
  height: 100%;   
  background-image: url("");
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: Don't take 100% of my height I post you a screenshot if you want

Comment: @Jonathan send me

Comment: Please, look this link : https://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2017/38/1/1505762885-capture-d-ecran-2017-09-18-a-21-24-18.png

Comment: Update, use this 

Comment: Same result, I try this solution before... I can't resolve my problem I don't understand why